# Run bash function with parallel

Tags: bash, parallel-processing

I have a bash script to check more 30000 sites.

my function is:

```
check_site() {
  host=$1; ip=$2

  resp=$(curl -i -m1 -H "Host: $host" http://$ip 2>&1)
  echo "$resp" | grep -Eo "$ok" > /dev/null

  if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    echo -e "Command: curl -i -m1 -H \"Host: $host\" http://$ip 2>&1" >> "${outlog}"
    echo -e "Block failed: $host:\n\"$resp\"\n\n" >> "${outlog}"

    httpresponse=$(echo "$resp" | grep HTTP/1.1)
    echo "$host $ip $httpresponse" >> "${faillog}"
  fi
}
```

and I call the function:

```
...
check_site $host $ip
...
```

Is it possible to use parallel call my function passing arguments `$host` and `$ip`?

Comment: `check_site $host $ip &` then after the loop, `wait`. You should probably write to a unique file per query though and then concatenate them all after the `wait`.

Comment: Assuming your goal is to "run" thru the list as fast as possible. look at `xargs` or `gnu-parallel`. You will ultimately be resource bound by your network connection and possibly RAM usage of calling X copies of `curl` at the same time. Good luck.

Comment: Presumably you don't type in 30,000 sites by hand, so you must have some sort of list of addresses but you don't show its format...

Comment: Check this approach https://www.golinuxcloud.com/run-shell-scripts-in-parallel-collect-exit-status-process/

Comment: Hi @shellter thanks for the reply. Do you know if can I pass the input variables to ```gnu-parallel``` without write them in a txt file before?

Comment: @MarkSetchell the format is url ip, for example: ```www.google.com 10.10.10.10```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved writing input variables in a txt file and using `gnu-parallel`:

```
...
echo "$host $ip" >> "${tempfile}"
...
export -f check_site 

export outlog="/tmp/out.log"
export faillog="/tmp/fail.log"
parallel --colsep ' ' -j 252 -a "${tempfile}" check_site
```

Comment: Arg. typo! .. Fixed it now --- Good show! Solving your problem after getting some hints is always fun! ... You maybe able to avoid the temp file if `parallel` supports `-` to read from stdin. Try `list-producing-code|parallel --colsep ' ' -j 252 -a - check_site` or check the documentation for feeding from stdin. Good luck!

Comment: You _can_ do `parallel -a -` but the shorter version of that is `parallel`, because `parallel` reads from stdin (standard input) by default.